# Kendo dropzone looks more like stack

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am working on a project where the user has option to upload file or paste a link. I like the way stack is doing it and wanted to see if I can get my kendo to look more like it. I dont see a way to replace the button with a browse or text. Is there a way I can edit the `Select files...` button section?

```js
$("#photos").kendoUpload({
  async: {
    saveUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/save",
    removeUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/remove",
    autoUpload: true
  },
  complete: onComplete,
  upload: onUpload,
  localization: {
    dropFilesHere: "Browse, drag & drop, or <a id=displayLink>paste</a> an image or link"
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevitt/ItEWuTim

[image: Stack Overflow's file uploader]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the Select files button can be changed via the [localization.select](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/localization.select) configuration - [updated example](https://dojo.telerik.com/AZarezuY)

Comment: Anyway I can combine that  link control ?

Comment: You can make the button look like a link by removing some of the default classes and adding the `k-button-link` class and `k-button-link-{themeColor}` to style the link [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/AZarezuY/3)

Comment: But can’t  add input control that will take in a user input ?

Comment: I have included anohter picture to help you understand what I was looking for. When you select that paste it turn that drop zone to a input text.

Comment: Besides plain text you can also add an element and an additional click handler to it, to [show an input](https://dojo.telerik.com/ExIBivuV).